# isinstance(df, pd._libs.tslib.Timestamp) what does it do?

Tags: pandas, timestamp

what does this function do exactly? here df is a dataframe with timestamp as index.For example, below DataFrame df:

2018-12-13 09:00:00, -113.0

2018-12-13 10:00:00, -112.5

2018-12-13 11:00:00, -114.8

if isinstance(df, pd._libs.tslib.Timestamp):

What does this if check do?

Answer (score 1):

Access the Timestamp class as `pd.Timestamp` and skip the middle part, it's clearer.

You are testing whether the Dataframe is a single Timestamp. A Dataframe can contain columns of different data types - like Timestamps.

Some examples of your case:

```
    import pandas as pd

    dt_single = pd.Timestamp("2019-01-01")
    dt_column = [pd.Timestamp("2019-01-01") + pd.Timedelta(days=n) for n in range(3)]
    values = np.random.rand(3)
    df = pd.DataFrame({"dt_column": dt_column, "values": values})

    print(isinstance(df, pd.Timestamp))  # False. Type = pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
    print(isinstance(df["dt_column"], pd.Timestamp))  # False. Type = pandas.core.series.Series
    print(isinstance(dt_single, pd.Timestamp))  # True
```